# Inconsistent type in golang, cannot use <Type> as *Type

Tags: go, pdf

Hello I have the next code in Golang:

```
func createPDF(count int)   {
    pdfFile := pdf.NewMaroto(consts.Portrait, consts.A4)
    pdfFile.SetPageMargins(10, 15, 10)
    writeGroups(pdfFile)
}

func  writeGroups(pdf *pdf.Maroto) {
    //Do something
}
```

If I send it as (&pdfFile) I'm not able to use its methods, I'm just seeing:

[image]

I would like to pass this pdf variable as a pointer to the writeGroups method and I'm getting a Cannot use type (Maroto)  as type * pdf.Maroto in Golang. I'm new in the language, is that possible to do. What the issue means?

Thanks

Comment: You have to pass the pointer to the struct (&pdfFile)

Comment: Thanks, a question why I cannot use the pdfFile methods if I send it like &pdfFile?

Comment: What do you mean? I thought passing by pointer fixed it for you? Need to see more code to answer that but I'm guessing the methods on your pdf struct are private (aka starts with a lower case letter).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you are using https://github.com/johnfercher/maroto
`pdf.Maroto` is an interface and you can pass that into your function by reference without turning it into a pointer to an interface.

So if you change your function to

```
func  writeGroups(pdf pdf.Maroto) {
    //Do something
}
```

You should now be able to call the interface functions on pdf.Maroto. Those functions definition are defined for pdf.Maroto and not *pdf.Maroto which is why you could not use them.

Alternatively if you are sure you need a pointer to the pdf.Maroto function, you could dereference the pointer then call the function you want.

```
func  writeGroups(pdf *pdf.Maroto) {
    (*pdf).AddPage()
}
```